# Powershell - Multiple parameters - Conditions

Tags: powershell, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to create a script in powershell, that does several things depending on which parameters is set or not. My code looks like the following:

```
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [String]$var1 ,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)]
    [int]$var2 ,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=3)]
    [int]$var3 ,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=4)]
    [string]$var4
)
....
```

And then i want to either do a if-elseif to check which parameters is set:

```
if (!$var2 -and !$var3 -and !$var4) {
  ... Do something with $var1 
} elseif (!$var2 -and !$var3 -and $var4) {
 ... Do something with $var1 and $var4
} else {
 throw an error
}
```

.. or do a switch case if that is more suitable. I cant decide whether or not it is. Can anyone come up with a small example to do this? Thanks in advance. And Thank you for taking your time to help me out.

Comment: Good question though I'm not sure if this might be opinion based. `Switch` is more elegant and easier to read imo. You can also use `$PSBoundParameters` too.

Comment: You can also use `switch` with multiple `return` statements in addition to [Mathias's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68210863/15339544).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Mathias great answer, when you have multiple conditions I find the easiest way to do this is to use guard clauses.  **Guard Clauses** are these dead-simple little functions that return a true/false value.

If you string these along in your `if` blocks, it makes the logic very, very easy to follow.  Much easier than repeatedly checking for values from `PSBoundParameters`, IMHO.

Here's an example.

```
function isRed {
    param([string]$ForegroundColor)
    $ForegroundColor -eq 'Red'
}

function isInt {
    param($object)
    $object -is [int]
}
```

These are so simple you may look at them and say 'why even bother'.  Here's why!

Once we have them we can call them in a parent function, and since these just return true/false, they fit right into the `if` condition, like this:

```
#updating Mathias to add calling the guard clauses
function Write-CustomHost {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $Object,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [ValidateSet('Red','Green')]
    [string]$ForegroundColor
  )

  Write-Host @PSBoundParameters
  
  if (isRed $ForegroundColor -and isInt $Object){
    "this is a red Int, so lets do special handling here"
  }
}

Write-CustomHost -Object 1 -ForegroundColor Red
```

[image]

You can achieve advanced complexity in your code and maintain legibility by implementing simple guard clauses.  Others on your team or future you will thank yourself for doing it!

Comment: I'd _strongly_ recommend `$Object -is [int]` in place of `$Object.GetType().Name -eq [Int].Name` :-)

Comment: Good call, I didn't know PowerShell exposed an `-is` operator!

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable - it's a special dictionary/hashtable that contains the argument values passed to the function by the caller:

```
if(!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('var2') -and !$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('var3') -and !$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('var4')){
    # only $var1 has an argument value
}
```

The nice thing about `$PSBoundParameters` being a hashtable is that if you want to pass optional arguments to another function, you can just [splat it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting):

```
function Write-CustomHost {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $Object,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [ValidateSet('Red','Green')]
    [string]$ForegroundColor
  )

  Write-Host @PSBoundParameters
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Mathias. That was my first touch on PSBoundParameters. :D Very cool feature.